# Setting Volume Host Path from Docker Run command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a DockerFile that defines two volumes...

```
VOLUME /XXX/XXX1
VOLUME /XXX/XXX2
```

I am running...

```
docker build -t XXX .
```

Followed by...

```
docker run XXX:latest —v XXX:XXX
```

I can see the Volume Bindings in the Rider Docker window but the don't have the Host Paths set.

If I manually update them in the Rider IDE the application works as expected when started.

Why aren't my Host Paths being set by the command?
What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: in your home directory (or any directory with files in it), run 'docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD":/work -w /work alpine:latest ls'. If that works, then docker is working ok. Btw: your docker run should map xxx:xxx/xxx1 not xxx:xxx

Comment: In your `docker run -v` option it matters what the `XXX` are; can you make the command a little more representative of what you're actually running?